# Making enter the same as button in java, android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't find anything about the thing i need.
When the user is typing his stuff in the `editText` he has to press a `button` to perform a task. What i want to do is that when he presses Enter on the keyboard, it would be equivalent to the button task.

[image: ss]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use and EditiorActionListener

```
editBox.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
    //button action}
    return false;
    }
});
```